# How can I determine the distance between cities for "Glorious Reikland" map?

Tags: maps, travel, wfrp-4e

I started the creation of a campaign for WFRP4e settled in the Reikland, the main country of the core rulebook.

I used the map in order to create a path for caravans, but I need to know distances between cities. I looked for a map caption like the image below but found nothing. Same goes for the book section "Glorious Reikland p267.

[image: map scale example]

Since I do not have information about the "size" of the country, I can't guess.
Is there any information, clues or anything else that may allow me to deduce the distance between cities?

[Map of Reikland](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/warhammerfb/images/e/e2/Reikland_Map_Cubicle_4th_Edition.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20191017163446)

I have also contacted the artist who created the map in order to ask him more details and information about the map, icons etc. No response yet.

I'm looking for official information, but any "guess" from fans is also welcome since it is not certain that official distances exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unofficial PDF ["Travel Distances in the Empire (and beyond)" by Jackdays](http://www.gitzmansgallery.com/docs/Travel%20Distances%20in%20the%20Empire.pdf) will be useful to you.

Page 2 of the PDF explains how to read the entry and the sources of the information:

> Following travelling distances are based on the various maps, that should be credited here. First number is average based on the next two. Second number is based on the **Gitzmans Map** (collected and modified from the maps made originally by **Alfred Nunez Jr** and **Andreas Blicher**) – Great work! Third number is based on the official maps made by Andy Law – River Map (*Warhammer Companion*, WFRP2), Thousand Thrones Campaign Map (*The Thousand Thrones*, WFRP2), Kislev Map (*Realm of the Ice Queen*, WFRP2), Border Princes Map (*Renegade Crowns*, WFRP2) and also Andy’s huge map about the Empire.

It lists distances between various cities and it would be a good starting point to figure out the scale of the map. For example, use the distance from Altdorf to Nuln and measure that distance, divide it by the number of cm, and there you have your km-per-cm measurement.

> Altdorf – Nuln: 315 (260 / 370) miles Road (Altdorf-Nuln Road)

Useful link: [How to measure the distance of a walk on a map with string.](https://babyroutes.co.uk/measure-distance-walk-map-string/)